# Can I grab and populate a screen made by a programmatically triggered button push?

Tags: acumatica

Am I able to grab a screen that is created by a programmatically triggered button push call and populate it with values?

My specific example is that I want to grab the new e-mail screen that is made when I execute this code:

```
CRCommunicationDraft graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRCommunicationDraft>();
graph.AddNew.PressButton();
```

I want to grab the screen created after AddNew.PressButton() is executed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, I think is answered here:

[How can I open an editable, sendable e-mail screen with prepopoulated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250950/how-can-i-open-an-editable-sendable-e-mail-screen-with-prepopoulated-values/47267347#47267347)

For most cases you want to:

1. Override the Action Handler of the button. You can use OVERRIDE METHOD button of customization editor for that. In your case override the AddNew action event handler.
2. Create a new graph instance for your target screen, here it is CREmailActivityMaint.
3. Assign to or insert a record into the current DataView of that graph, in your case use CREmailActivityMaint.Message DataView.
4. Redirect to the screen, using PXRedirectHelper class.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I remember about the override of the action now that you mention it, but didn't  realize I could override the AddNew action.