# How can I open an editable, sendable e-mail screen with prepopoulated values?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an e-mail with to and from already filled in. To create the e-mail, I'm creating a graph instance of CREmailActivityMaint. Whenever I attempt to assign new objects to the CREmailActivityMaint.CurrentMessage or CREmailActivityMaint.Message objects so that I can set values, the opening page becomes uneditable and Send is hidden:

[image]

Also when I enter values, not all of them show. In this,  I entered To, From, Subject, Summary, and Body, but Body and Summary show nothing. Also if I attempt to save, I get an error stating that the Summary, To, and Subject are blank:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREmailActivityMaint graph = CreateInstance<CREmailActivityMaint>();
    graph.Message.Current = graph.Message.Insert();
    graph.Message.Current.MailTo = "other@test.com";
    graph.Message.Current.MailCc = "another@test.com";
    graph.Message.Current.MailBcc = "bcc@test.com";
    graph.Message.Current.Subject = "Subject";
    graph.Message.Current.Body = "Body";
    graph.Message.Cache.IsDirty = false;
    PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know when I should use .Current =  .Insert() vs .Current = new object()?

Comment: You use insert to let the system handle key fields initialization and parent-child relationship between tables (Identity, RecordNo, Segmentend Keys etc.) . If you create new object, those fields will be left blank when persisting so you'd have to fill them in manually, otherwise it will throw a key can't be blank error.

Comment: Most screens needs the keys to be properly filled in for their primary DataView current record so I recommend to go for Insert and use new object only for edge cases where you want to manually set the keys.

Comment: Alright, good advice! Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I have another question regarding .Insert(). If I create an object and populate it then use graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(object), does that auto populate the necessary keys still?

Comment: No idea, you'd have to try it and debug.